# 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'microseconds'

Tags: python, datetime, error-handling, attributeerror

I am writing a script in *python* and I need to know how many milliseconds are between two points in my code.

I have a global variable when the program starts like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
a=datetime.now()
```

When I need to know how many milliseconds have passed, I execute this:

```
  b=datetime.now()
  print (b.microseconds-a.microseconds)*1000
```

However I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'microseconds'
```

What's wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is `microsecond`, without an "s" at the end

Answer (score 1):

A useful function is `dir`. You can do `dir(object)` to find out its properties. In this case, you want `a.microsecond`.

Comment: Or use tab autocompletion of dotted attributes if you're in the `ipython` shell